# Are MySQL in-memory tables global?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, in-memory

I have a **MySQL** stored routine where I'd like to use a temporary data table to store intermediate results. To avoid having to create a "normal" table, I want to use an in-memory table that goes away when routine execution has completed. I'm a MySQL newbie, but I suppose this is the way to go:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyInMemoryTable;
CREATE TABLE MyInMemoryTable ( numberField int ) ENGINE = MEMORY;
...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyInMemoryTable;
```

My routine works for a single user, but I am nervous about what happens if *multiple users* run the routine *at the same time*?

Is `MyInMemoryTable` **local** to each user session executing the routine, so there can be many instances of this table (without conflicts) at the same time?
Or is `MyInMemoryTable` a single **global** table for all users, thereby risking different users' data getting mixed-up in the table? Or will one user risk getting a database error if another user is busy running the routine?

To me, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) is confusing: It says the `MEMORY` engine associates each table with a disk file, but also that "`MEMORY` tables are never converted to disk tables."

Have I misunderstood MySQL in-memory tables? Perhaps there's a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...;
```

Those tables aren't shared and are deleted when your connection ends.

The standard in memory tables are probably shared and global.

Comment: Oh, that's what I suspected. I got it all wrong. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

These are two different concepts: table engine and table temporary property. In theory, a table with any engine can be temporary (InnoDB, MyISAM, Memory). [Memory engine is perhaps least understood storage engine in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html). Under the hood, it's an incrementally growing hash map. 
So, yes, in-memory tables can be session local - but they have to be temporary for that:

```
mysql> show create table tmp; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp` (   `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 | 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table tmp; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table tmp; CREATE TABLE `tmp` (   `example` int(11) NOT NULL,   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   PRIMARY KEY (`example`),   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```