# month on month fund return (%)

Tags: mysql, sql, return

I made MySQL database contains below data:

```
Date (date) | NAV Decimal(30,10)
```

Each date is a month end date.

It has monthly Fund NAV for the past 3 years like below.

```
2012-12-31 |105

2013-01-28 | 100

2013-02-28 | 105
```

I would like to calculate month on month return in percentage using the NAV column and display each month's return for the 3 years period.

Kindly advice how I can make MySQL query.

Expected results are as below:

```
2013-01-31 |-5%

2013-02-28 |5%
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not loop for calculation  in SQL. For this you have to use MySql stored procedure/function or you have to code in any server side language with mysql library Api

You can have idea of stored procedure here:

[Looping Over Result Sets in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql-resolved-using-cursors)