# MySQL Stored Procedure with

Tags: mysql

I have an Stored Procedure which does make an UPDATE for more than one rows. But it doesn't work.
Below is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dbnine`.`vacores` ()
BEGIN

SET @a = (
SELECT acores from infos_bureau
where agent = '');

SET @b = (
SELECT DISTINCT agent from infos_bureau
where acores = @a
AND agent !='');

UPDATE infos_bureau set agent = @b
WHERE agent = '';

END
```

I want to know is it possible to make a loop inside?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

study example from below link..

[Looping Over Result Sets in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql-resolved-using-cursors)