# How to access a line by its index in mysql cusor?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-view

I have a view with the following informations:

```
date, n1, n2, n3, n4, day, month, year, some_id, unix_timesamp, mean, std
'29/5/2007', '28', '5', '0', '0.1786', '29', '5', '2007', '5', '1180411981', null, null
...
...
```

And I'd like to compute the mean and standard deviation of `n4` for the past `y` days. The results of the view are already grouped by days.

If I were using a standard programming language, my algorithm would look like this:

```
//For each line
for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
  //We have advanced enough days to compute average
  //and std
  if(i > y){
     //Stores the values of the past y days
     float[] values = new float[y];
     int z = 0;
     //Loop over the past y days
     for(int j = i - y; j < i; j++){
        values[z] = rows[j].n4;
        z++;
     }
     //compute mean and std
     rows[i].mean = mean(values);
     rows[i].std = std(values);
   }
}
```

Now, I can't find how I could do this while staying within mysql (yes, I *really* have to). I started playing around with cursor and temp table as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745165/looping-over-result-sets-in-mysql) but I don't know how to access a given row which is needed for the inner loop. I also tried using a subquery for the inner loop but the view contains ~100k lines and it was taking ~0.3 sec per line in order to requery the view (using a function to select only the  `y` days and compute the mean and std for a given line).

The content provided by the view is constantly updated so the mean and std have to be computed at users' request. I can't compute it once and store it in a dedicated table.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a cursor for this?  It is more easily expressed using a set-based query:

```
select avg(n4), stddev(n4)
from t
where date >= curdate() - interval by day;
```

For optimal performance you would want an index on `(date, n4)`.

Comment: Well, this is the kind of subquery I had. However, it was way too long to compute. That' s why I experienced with cursor.

Comment: @MathieuNls . . . A cursor is not going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing requires [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), which are being added in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2. As of January 2018, neither of these versions are available as stable releases yet.

Once these features are available in a stable version of the database, I believe this syntax will work. (I'm guessing based on the documentation, as I don't have a MySQL 8.0 alpha installed to test against.)

```
SELECT
    date,
    AVG(n4) OVER w,
    STDDEV(n4) OVER w
FROM table_name
WINDOW w AS (
    ORDER BY date
    ROWS BETWEEN y PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```